# Why can't I override the bootstrap class of "nav-link" and change the color of the link text?

Tags: html, css

If I get rid of the class of "nav-link" for the "a" tags, then I can change the text color. But then I lose all the other settings like padding.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link white" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
```

Comment: With the CDN, you'd need `!important` with almost every CSS change you write for the Bootstrap classes.

Comment: What does your browser's dev tools inspect facility show are the CSS settings? You should be able to trace back to see who/where is setting any property - and whether they have say !important set.

Answer (score 0):

`nav-link` has the styles from Bootstrap. The `a` tag loses the style if you remove the class name from it.

[image]

To add your own style, you need to declare your style in a class and add it in the `a` tag. If you want to make sure your style overrides bootstraps style, you might want to use `!important`.